# Write-Host fails in Invoke-Command in InlineScript in Workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I have something like this:

```
workflow WF {
    foreach -Parallel ($computer in $computers) {
        $results = InlineScript {
            $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Using:computer
            return Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                 Write-Host "Test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I'll get an error:

```
A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command
type does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user
interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE,
and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user
interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Write-Host], HostException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HostFunctionNotImplemented,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

How can I get the `Write-Host` output to the computer running the script? Note that I'm returning something else inside the ScriptBlock so I cannot just return the string and `Write-Host` it.

Comment: `... because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction` - don't use `Write-Host` in a remote session, use `Write-Output` (or `Write-Information` if you you're on version 5+) if you want information back from the remote runspace

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inline

```
 inlineScript
    {
    Write-Host "Allow"
    }
```

Comment: Please mark this answer, if the above suggestion works for you